# Declaring and initialising a variable in a using block

Tags: c#, variables, using

After a bit of advice here, regarding best practice coding - I am still a beginner with regards to C#.  I have been reading on how using blocks are essential for disposing objects and attempting to implement these.

My question however, is if you are declaring and initialising a variable, should this be in a using block also?

I have tested and it seems to compile fine.  But would appreciate peoples thoughts on this.

Thanks,

Comment: You can **only** use `using` statement with those objects which implements `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: You should declare and use variables in the smallest scope possible

Comment: Just a clarification. `using` doesn't do anything for disposing the object itself. That's all handled by the garbage collector and you don't need to do anything special for that to happen. The `using` construct is used to dispose of resources that aren't handled by GC.

Comment: You don't *have* to declare the variable in the using block.  Not doing so makes little sense, there's just not much you can do with the variable after the using block since it refers to a dead object that ought to just generate an ObjectDisposedException when you try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using blocks are only helpful with objects that implement the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. It roughly translates to having a try...finally block that disposes the object in the finally. You can see more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is common practice to declare a variable closest to where you need it. If it not used outside of the using block (or any other block) there's usually no reason to declare it outside.

Answer (score 0):

No. Putting any variable inside a using is just not necessary. It's basically help for the RAII idiom, which in .NET is commonly useful only for objects that wrap / use an unmanaged resource. And the standard pattern for those objects is to implement a IDisposable. The `using` keyword is just some nice syntax sugar for

```
try{ 
  //initialize and use variable 
} 
finally { 
  //cast to IDisposable - if not null, call Dispose()
}
```

So even though it will compile and work, it's no use at all if your object doesn't implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "Should this be in the using block also?" is truly a matter of scope.  Variables declared in the scope of your block (try, using, etc) will fall out of scope when the block is exited.

Consider the following two examples:

1. Declare variable, assign in block, exit block, require variable.

   ```
   WebHeaderCollection headers;

   using (var cl = new WebClient())
   {
       headers = cl.ResponseHeaders;
   }

   // headers is still in scope
   foreach (var k in headers.AllKeys) 
       Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", k, headers[k]);
   ```
2. Declare and assign variable in block, exit block, require variable

   ```
   using (var cl = new WebClient())
   {
       var headers = cl.ResponseHeaders;

       // use headers here, just fine
       foreach (var k in headers.AllKeys) 
           Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", k, headers[k]);
   }

   // headers is no longer in scope
   foreach (var k in headers.AllKeys) 
       Debug.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", k, headers[k]);
   ```

Option #2 throws an exception.  So, first determine the scope requirement of your variable and then decide if you need it after the using block ends.